# how to have publication from thesis?

Tags: publications, research-process, thesis

I have studied for two semesters so far, I got a research proposal from my supervisor now and I am reviewing it. It is crucial for me to have at least 2-3 papers based on my thesis. I am thinking of asking my professors about doing a literature review. 
What kinda things we should expect from our supervisor? I think the student needs to be active instead of the supervisor. What kinda things the student can do in order to processed in his/her thesis and get it done in the expected time?

I appreciate any advice that comes from you.

Edit: There are not enough courses related to my thesis, so is this a problem? what can I do?

Comment: @JeffE, What do you mean by "two-semester ago"?'

Comment: According to your first sentence, you've been studying for about two semesters.  These would have been great questions to ask your supervisor when (or even before) you started.

Comment: @JeffE, is it late to talk about this now? professor won't like talking about it?

Comment: No, it’s also a good question now. In fact, it really ought to be a regular topic of conversation between you and your supervisor. Start now!.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, talk to your supervisor. S/he is the best guide for this and knows the expectations of your field and university.

For another view, talk to other students who have done this and get an idea about what is expected and how to go about it. It is highly dependent on field and on local practice.

I doubt that a literature review is sufficient here, though it is necessary for the thesis.

But, technically, it isn't that the publications *come from the thesis*. Actually, they come from the *research results* that will become the thesis.

So, examine your research. Find what results you have achieved that are "interesting" and "novel." Build your publications around those. What are the results? What is the supporting evidence? What directions does this suggest for the future.

Once you have enough of that, you have the basis of the thesis.

Note that the above is only one view. The other is that the thesis itself is publishable in whole or in part. The idea is really the same, except that you finish the thesis before you publish one or more papers based on the thesis as a whole or on interesting parts of it.